# How do I send a message to the ViewController's View?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa

I'm returning to iOS development after a long while away so apologies for having to ask such a basic question.

I'm creating a single view app. I've created a class `DrawingBoard` that subclasses from `UIImageView`. The `ViewController` set up in Main.Storyboard remains unchanged from the boiler plate except that I've changed the view controller's view from `View` class to `DrawingBoard`. In interface builder, I right click on 'View Controller' and I see that 'Drawing Board' is listed as an outlet.

All, so far is good. I start the app. `DrawingBoard` is instantiated and responds to touches.

But now I want to send `DrawingBoard` a message from `ViewController`. I have a public method set up in `@interface` in the header and that method is implemented in `.m`. ...I can't send the message. The view controller doesn't seem to know about `DrawingBoard`. What have I missed?

```
//
//  DrawingBoard.h
//  DrawingBoard

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface DrawingBoard : UIImageView {}
-(void)testMe;
@end
```

...

```
//
//  DrawingBoard.m
//  DrawingBoard
//
#import "DrawingBoard.h"

// ...

-(void)testMe {
    NSLog(@"/n/n/nTested!/n/n/n/");
}
```

I try to message `DrawingBoard` from `ViewController` as follows:

```
[self.view testMe]
```

Comment: What does your question have to do with Cocoa?

Answer (score 0):

You could say

```
[(DrawingBoard*)self.view testMe];
```

But don't. Put the image view *in* the view controller's main view; don't make it *be* the view controller's main view. And then make an IBOutlet so the view controller can get a reference to it.

Comment: By the way, you seem barely to know Objective-C, so why not scrap it and learn Swift now that you're back? It's a much better beginner language.